# textbox take only numeric value and not take zero at the starting

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new in javascript and i want to validate textbox from javascript.textbox should take only numeric value and should not take zero at the starting.

I tried below function that works fine but not understand how to avoid zero from First Position.

below is my html code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="cp1_txtMob" palceholder="10 digit mobile No." ondrop="return false;" onPaste="return false;" runat="server" class="textfile_new2" Style="color: #333;" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event);"  MaxLength="10" autocomplete="OFF"></asp:TextBox>

function isNumberKey(e) {
    var t = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((t >= 48 && t <= 57) || (t >= 96 && t <= 105) || (t == 8 || t == 9 || t == 127 || t == 37 || t == 39 || t == 46))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it `onkeyup="AvoidZero(this.id);"` like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="cp1_txtMob" palceholder="10 digit mobile No." ondrop="return false;" onPaste="return false;" runat="server" class="textfile_new2" Style="color: #333;" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event);"  MaxLength="10" autocomplete="OFF" onkeyup="AvoidZero(this.id);"></asp:TextBox>

function AvoidZero(v) { 
    var V = document.getElementById(v).value; 
        return (V.charAt(0) == 0) ? (document.getElementById(v).value = V.substring(1, V.length), false) : false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use isNaN() for such comparisions.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp